# zlib compress/uncompress c++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, zlib

So I have a question I can't seem to find the answer for.

If I containually compress small char arrays and add them to a larger character array, can I uncompress that large character array at once and get back all my original data?

For instance:

```
char arry1 = "Today is";
char arry2 = " a nice day";
char arryBig[20];

//pseudo code for compress, but you get the idea
compress(arry1)

strcpy(arryBig, arry1);

//again, pseudo code for compress
compress(arry2);

strcpy(arryBig+9, arry2);

uncompress(arryBig);

//does arryBig == "today is a nice day" ??
```

Comment: I guess you'd have to come up with your own compression algorithm to support that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. The result of compression is a complex structure that you cannot simply concatenate. And even if you could, you shouldn't be doing it with strcpy since the output of compress() may very well contain null-characters.

It's also a bad idea because the compression ratio will be much better for longer runs of data.

If you are looking for some kind of streaming solution, your only option is to buffer your input until you are ready to compress. If, on the other hand, you are looking for some zip-archive like thing, there is code on the zlib website to help you create zip archives.